# Confluence-api querying

Tags: node.js, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to use the npm packaged called [confluence-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confluence-api#Confluence+search) as a wrapper to query a number of things in my Confluence instance. For the life of me, I cannot get the cql portion to work. When I point a browser to `http://<wiki>/rest/api/content?search?cql=created%20>%20now("-4h")`, I get a listing of pages created in the last 4 hours.

When I try the same thing in my node.js app, I get an 404.

```
var query = 'cql=created%20>%20now("-4h")';
confluence.search(query, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

I've tried other features of this npm package and it works fine so it's not a permission issue.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working as long as config.version is not 4 (checking the code of confluence-api, the API path is changed when the version is 4 and resulting to problems). Here's a [sample working code via RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/cnbqccjnarqc).

Comment: I'm starting to think it may be a configuration issue with my Confluence instance. I'll poke around there and see if I can figure out if the server is blocking REST searches (unlikely as all other REST operations work fine).

Comment: Is the sample code in RunKit working for you? There's also a test instance you there that you can run your calls against.

Comment: Yes, the sample code in RunKit works for me but when I run it against my Confluence instance, it doesn't. I've checked various settings and permissions and nothing looks out of the ordinary. I'm effectively stuck but I may use the exec method to just execute a curl operation using the aforementioned URL. :(